# react app feature works on production but not on deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I'm creating a simple calculator using the react CRA. I have a feature, that when you press a math operator (+-*/) it's displayed on the screen. It works fine in production, but when I deploy the app, it just disappears. Never shows.

Here's the code for the calculator screen:

```
const CalcScreen = ({ operation, screen }) => {
    const operationSymbol = () => {
        if (operation) {
            switch (operation.name) {
                // ? adds the correct symbol
                case 'add':
                    return '+';
                case 'substract':
                    return '-';
                case 'multiply':
                    return 'x';
                case 'divide':
                    return '/';
                default:
                    return '';
            }
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    };
    return (
        <CalcScreenSty>
            <div className="screen__operation">{operationSymbol()}</div>
            <div className="screen__number">{screen}</div>
        </CalcScreenSty>
    );
};
```

It's that simple. I have a state, then when that state changes, the `operationSymbol` function does the switch to try and match the operation (`operation` is a state that has a function inside and changes every time I press a math operation button, so I need the name of the function, that's why the operation.name), and if none is found, meaning there's no operation being made, then returns an empty string.
In production that works, I have the operation symbol when needed, but when I deploy it, the symbol never shows.

I tried even deleting the app, cloning, installing and deploying again but didn't work either. I tried it in Firefox, or in my phone, but none work. The operator just never shows.

I'm doing the deploy using react-gh-pages

Here's the deploy page if you need it: https://gusvianadev.github.io/calculator/

Am I missing something? Is it just a bug or is there something wrong with my code that works on production but not on deploy?

Comment: You are using the function name to find the operation that's a bad practice. While creating the build the files get minified and variable name changes to some random characters.

Comment: I'll try and change how I get the symbol then. I'll get back to you on that in a min.

Comment: That was actually the problem. Thx man, I didn't know that variable names change to random characters. Thanks!